# Make parent name active in the menu when I'm in its child page

Tags: php, jquery, css, recursion

I have this recursive function:

```
function recursive($arrays, $out) {
if (is_array($arrays)){
     //$out .= "<ul>";
     foreach($arrays as $parent => $data) {
         //if parent is empty
         if ($parent === '') {
             $out = recursive($data, $out);
             continue;
         }

         $out .= "<li>";
         if (is_array($data)){
             $out .= ' <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">';$out .= $parent;
         }
         else
         { $directory =explode("@", $parent)[0];$paname = explode("@", $parent[1]; $link = 'http://127.0.0.1/ocos/index.php?module='.$directory.'/'.$paname;
             $out .= '<a href="'.$link.'">'; $out .= $data;

         }

         if (is_array($data)){
              $out .= '<b class="caret"></b></a>';
         }
         else
         {
             $out .= "</a>";
         }
         if (is_array($data)){
            $out .= "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
            $out = recursive($data, $out);
            $out .= "</ul></li>";
         }
         else
         {
         $out .= "</li>"; 
         }
     }
    }
```

return $out; 
}

In the menu bar I have a dropdown menu with parent called`operation` and with a child page called `aro` and `aro` have another child page called `aro document list` so all I wanna is that when I'm in `aro document list` make the parent `operation` active with green color to make the user know in which part of the menu he is in. Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it too complicated. Is the below what you need? When you click on a,b or c the parent will get a green background.

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
  var grandparent = $(this).parent("ul").parent("li");
  if (grandparent.length > 0) {
    grandparent.css("background", "green");
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: white;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.operations {
  display: flex;
}

.operations li {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="operations">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3
    <ul class="aro">
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when i click on the page and load it i want to make the operation active as a green not when i clicked , for example if im in page called index.php and i went to aro to php i want to make the paretn of aro.php wich is openrations in menu bar active as green etc @Gerard